# How to use feature extraction with DStream in Apache Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, feature-extraction, dstream

I have data that arrive from Kafka through DStream. I want to perform feature extraction in order to obtain some keywords.

I do not want to wait for arrival of all data (as it is intended to be continuous stream that potentially never ends), so I hope to perform extraction in chunks - it doesn't matter to me if the accuracy will suffer a bit.

So far I put together something like that:

```
def extractKeywords(stream: DStream[Data]): Unit = {

  val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate

  val streamWithWords: DStream[(Data, Seq[String])] = stream map extractWordsFromData

  val streamWithFeatures: DStream[(Data, Array[String])] = streamWithWords transform extractFeatures(spark) _

  val streamWithKeywords: DStream[DataWithKeywords] = streamWithFeatures map addKeywordsToData

  streamWithFeatures.print()
}

def extractFeatures(spark: SparkSession)
                   (rdd: RDD[(Data, Seq[String])]): RDD[(Data, Array[String])] = {

  val df = spark.createDataFrame(rdd).toDF("data", "words")

  val hashingTF = new HashingTF().setInputCol("words").setOutputCol("rawFeatures").setNumFeatures(numOfFeatures)
  val rawFeatures = hashingTF.transform(df)

  val idf = new IDF().setInputCol("rawFeatures").setOutputCol("features")
  val idfModel = idf.fit(rawFeatures)

  val rescaledData = idfModel.transform(rawFeature)

  import spark.implicits._
  rescaledData.select("data", "features").as[(Data, Array[String])].rdd
}
```

However, I received `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Haven't seen any document yet.` - I am not surprised as I just try out to scrap things together, and I understand that since I am not waiting for an arrival of some data, the generated model might be empty when I try to use it on data.

What would be the right approach for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used advises from comments and split the procedure into 2 runs:

- one that calculated IDF model and saves it to file

  ```
  def trainFeatures(idfModelFile: File, rdd: RDD[(String, Seq[String])]) = {
    val session: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate

    val wordsDf = session.createDataFrame(rdd).toDF("data", "words")

    val hashingTF = new HashingTF().setInputCol("words").setOutputCol("rawFeatures")
    val featurizedDf = hashingTF.transform(wordsDf)

    val idf = new IDF().setInputCol("rawFeatures").setOutputCol("features")
    val idfModel = idf.fit(featurizedDf)

    idfModel.write.save(idfModelFile.getAbsolutePath)
  }
  ```
- one that reads IDF model from file and simply runs it on all incoming information

  ```
  val idfModel = IDFModel.load(idfModelFile.getAbsolutePath)

  val documentDf = spark.createDataFrame(rdd).toDF("update", "document")

  val tokenizer = new Tokenizer().setInputCol("document").setOutputCol("words")
  val wordsDf = tokenizer.transform(documentDf)

  val hashingTF = new HashingTF().setInputCol("words").setOutputCol("rawFeatures")
  val featurizedDf = hashingTF.transform(wordsDf)

  val extractor = idfModel.setInputCol("rawFeatures").setOutputCol("features")
  val featuresDf = extractor.transform(featurizedDf)

  featuresDf.select("update", "features")
  ```